# How to merge by distance in geometry node for making quadrilater

Tags: modeling

I want to make quadrilateral using "curve line " node  but I'm unsuccsess .please tell me how can I make it  Note the the angle between the lines will variable .[image] Here you can have a loo on my blend file  [image] Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 3):

Don't make it harder for yourself, than it needs to be: define your corners, and pass them to your Curve Lines. Or you know what, pass them to Mesh Lines, so you don't need to convert them to meshes before merging:

[image]

Or you know what? Use the Quadrilateral node in *Points* mode:

[image]

Either way, changing the corner positions will change the shape:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you play with the merge by distance value and use the viewer node, you can get what you want, i think:

[image]

Note: fill curve only works on curves, where all z-values are 0.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/operations/fill_curve.html

I recommend changing your rotation + location to 0 so that you don't confuse yourself.

E.g. changing the values like this, will give you a parallelogramm (i muted your resample curve node).

[image]

and if you delete the resample curve node, and change your z-values to 0 and change the z-values to the x-values, you can fill it:

[image]